# laravel 8 multi sub-domains for every client

Tags: laravel

i need to make every client special subdomain

example :

company1.site.com

company2.site.com

try code but it's work fine with localhost but not working on shared host

```
class CheckTenantUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $has_access = $request->session()->get('has_access');
        if ($has_access) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        list($subdomain) = explode('.', $request->getHost(), 2);
        $tenant = Client::where('slug', $subdomain)->where('status',1)->firstOrFail();
        $request->session()->put('currentClient', $tenant);
        if ($request->user() == null) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        $has_access = $request->user()->tenant == $tenant;
        if (!$tenant) {
            return redirect('/login')->with('no_access', true);
        } else {
            $request->session()->put('has_access', true);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

now check for clients from database but and set subdomain by slug

i need how can make it work on shared host like localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can check a 3rd party package available for this - https://tenancyforlaravel.com/